# incrementing value using this object does not work

Tags: java

I have a class GridPosition with variable x in it. When I try to increment value of x using this.x+1 inside  incrementXaxis method then its not updating value in getter method.
I have to do this.setter(x) to update value of x.
As per my understanding this is current object so, if I do this.x+1 should work and return updated value when I call getter .

```
package com.robot.prob;

public class GridPosition {
    int x;

    public GridPosition(int x, int y, String f) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public int incrementXaxis(){
        return this.x+1;
    }
}
```

Please clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`return this.x+1` means return the value of x + 1 but it has no effect on x value.

Use  `return ++x` instead, it will add one to x and return the value of x.

Comment: `this.x++` would increment value of `x` but would return its old value.

Comment: `this.++x;` will not compile. Remove `this.` part as its purpose is to access class members, but `++` is operator.

Comment: I guess `++(this.x)` can be used.

Comment: @GaganGupta Yes, you can even drop parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int incrementXaxis() {
    return ++x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're not incrementing the value of `this.x` you're just returning whatever the value `this.x` is holding adding 1 to it.

so change it to this:

```
public int incrementXaxis(){
    return ++x;// x is the variable which will be accessed by `this` over here.
              // hence it will increment the value of x and then return it.
}
```